# Azure Batch JobPreparationTask fails with "UserError"

Tags: python, ubuntu, azure-batch

I am trying to mount a File Share (Not a blob storage) during the [JobPerparationTask](https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.batch.models.html?highlight=jobpreparationtask#azure.batch.models.JobPreparationTask). My node OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

To do this, I am doing the following:

```
job_user = batchmodels.AutoUserSpecification(
    scope=batchmodels.AutoUserScope.pool,
    elevation_level=batchmodels.ElevationLevel.admin)

start_task = batch.models.JobPreparationTask(command_line=start_commands, user_identity=batchmodels.UserIdentity(auto_user=job_user))
end_task = batch.models.JobReleaseTask(command_line=end_commands,user_identity=batchmodels.UserIdentity(auto_user=job_user))

job = batch.models.JobAddParameter(
    job_id,
    batch.models.PoolInformation(pool_id=pool_id),job_preparation_task=start_task, job_release_task=end_task)
```

My `start_commands` and `end_commands` are fine, but there is something wrong with the User permissions...

I get no output in the `stderr.txt` or in the `stdout.txt` file.
I do not see any logs what-so-ever (where are they?). All I am able to find is a message showing this:

```
Exit code
   1
Retry count
  0
Failure info
Category
  UserError
Code
  FailureExitCode
Message
  The task exited with an exit code representing a failure
Details
  Message: The task exited with an exit code representing a failure
```

Very detailed error message!

Anyway, I have also tried changing `AutoUserScope.oool` to `AutoUserScope.task`, but there is no change.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue which was frustrating me because I couldn't get any logs from my application.

What I ended up doing is RDP'ing into the node my job ran on, going to %AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR% as specified in [Azure Batch Compute Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-compute-node-environment-variables) and then checking the `stdout.txt` and `stderr.txt` in my job.

The error was that I formulated my `CloudTask`'s commandline incorrectly, so it could not launch my application in the first place.

To RDP into your machine, in Azure Portal:

1. Batch Account
2. Pools (select your pool)
3. Nodes
4. Select the node that ran your job
5. Select "Connect" link at the top.